# cycle2 with a folder as image-source

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, ipad, jquery-cycle2

I'm setting up an iPad-Kiosk and need to cycle through images as a slide-show.
Right now I use this very basic code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>test</title>
    <script src="jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.cycle2.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="cycle-slideshow">
    <img src="img/01.jpg">
    <img src="img/02.jpg">
    <img src="img/03.jpg">
    <img src="img/04.jpg">
    <img src="img/05.jpg">
    <img src="img/06.jpg">
    <img src="img/07.jpg">
    <img src="img/08.jpg">
    <img src="img/09.jpg">
    <img src="img/10.jpg">
    <img src="img/11.jpg">
    <img src="img/12.jpg">
    <img src="img/13.jpg">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

But what I really want is to autoload all image-files from a folder.
How can I populate a list of image-file-names using ajax/jQuery? Sadly I cannot use php.

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var image=1;

function checkImage(src) {
     var img = new Image();
     img.onload = function() {
     $('.cycle-slideshow').cycle('add','<img src="'+src+'">');
        };
 img.src = src;
}

function appendImage(){
            if(image<=9) 
                image='0'+image;
            var src = 'img/' +image+ '.jpg';
            checkImage(src);
            image=parseInt(image)+1;
};
```

This is how I did it finally. One disadvantage of this solution is that I call appendImage() about 100 times and just pretend that there are no more images. In my project that's ok, because there won't be more images to load but its a very crude solution.

Answer (score 1):

here you go, you need to loop through the folder with a variable to check the numbers, and an ajax call to see if the file exists:

```
var image=1;
function appendImage(){
    if(image<=9) image='0'+image;
    $.ajax({
        url:'img/'+image+'.jpg',
        type:'HEAD',
        success: function()
        {
            $('.cycle-slideshow').append('<img src="img/'+image+'.jpg">');
            image=parseInt(image)+1;
            appendImage();
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: I see your point. But when I call this function using
  $(function() {
  appendImage();
});
  </script>


I get:
              XMLHttpRequest cannot load file://......./img/01.jpg. Received an invalid response. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: you can not send an XML request on the local server, it means you need to put the code on a server to be able to send an ajax call!

Comment: Unfortunately this app has to run on an ipad as a standalone-kiosk in local mode (using kiosk-pro). Is there a workaround for this setup?

Comment: I've never worked with kiosk-pro therefore I don't know how or if there's a way to check if a file exist, but the idea is to check if the file exist, if it does, then append the img to the element, and add to the counter

Comment: I see. I like your solution very much but I guess the iPad-Kiosk-Pro doesn't allow XML requests in local mode. I need to find a different solution. thanks.